# Silverlight RadDataPager Binding

Tags: silverlight, telerik, pager

I've got a problem with the RadDataPager from Telerik... I can show all my users in the Gridview, but the pager doesn't set the next 5 users on the next page. They just all stand on my first page.

Anybody any idea?

Here is my code

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RadGridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding CovrUsers}" IsReadOnly="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CovrUsersViewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="230,5,0,0"
                             ScrollMode="Deferred"
                             GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >

            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="User name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hourly rate" DataMemberBinding="{Binding HourlyRate}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Rights" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Rights.Description}"  />
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>



        </telerik:RadGridView>
            <telerik:RadDataPager PageSize="5" IsTotalItemCountFixed="True" x:Name="RadDataPager1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding CovrUsers,ElementName=RadGridView1}"  Margin="230,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="11" />
```

Thx for the help!!

Comment: Do you have more than 5 users in the CovrUsers collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It's weird but it works :)

```
<telerik:RadGridView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RadGridView1" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding CovrUsers}" 
                             IsReadOnly="True" 
                             DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CovrUsersViewModel}}" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="230,5,0,0"
                             ScrollMode="Deferred"
                             GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >

            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="User name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Hourly rate" DataMemberBinding="{Binding HourlyRate}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Rights" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Rights.Description}"  />
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

        </telerik:RadGridView>
            <telerik:RadDataPager 
                PageIndexChanging="RadDataPager_PageIndexChanging"
                PageSize="5" 
                IsTotalItemCountFixed="True" 
                x:Name="RadDataPager" 
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                Source="{Binding Path=Items,ElementName=RadGridView1}" 
                DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CovrUsersViewModel}}" 
                Margin="230,0,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                FontSize="11"/>
```